# Ng-if with focus issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular 1.6 . Facing focus issue.Can anyone please suggest on this.

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" data-ng-click="showPan()">   Show</button>
        <div data-ng-if="showPanDiv">
        <input type="text" id="panInputId"/>
   </div>
```

**Controller**

In the controller I have the following code in inside the "showPan" method.

```
function showPan(){
   $scope.showPanDiv = true;
   $('#panInputId').focus();
}
```

But the focus is not going to the input element. If I use timeout, then it is going, like the below code.

```
function showPan(){
   $scope.showPanDiv = true;
   setTimeout(function(){
         $('#panInputId').focus();
   }, 100);

}
```

If the timeout time is zero or 10 , then also it is not working. If the time limit is more than or equal to 100, then it is working.

Similar question: If instead of ng-if , ng-include facing the same issue.

Can some one explain why it is not working ??? Or is there any solution to get the focus to the input element without using the timeout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write a **directive**:

```
app.directive('showFocus', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.showFocus, 
      function (newValue) { 
        $timeout(function() {
            newValue && element.focus();
        });
      },true);
  };    
});
```

And use it like:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="showPanDiv" show-focus="showPanDiv">
```

Reference [link](https://coderwall.com/p/a41lwa/angularjs-auto-focus-into-input-field-when-ng-show-event-is-triggered)

Comment: I have multiple input boxes in the div, and choosing dynamically the first element. after that setting focus to the first element. this piece of code wont help my solutin. That too it is not good idea to have $watch

Comment: Yeah, it will work fine anyway. The directive is for global use.

Comment: I am trying to understand the reason why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess time taking by ng-if to render is overlooking the focus issue. Try using ng-show and let me know if it works. 
Use ng-show instead of ng-if where you just want to hide and not re-render again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that hamzox wrote should be the accepted answer. You should never use jquery in angular controllers. **Directives are used for DOM manipulation.**

More about why directives are used for DOM manipulation: [Handle DOM Events the Angular Way Without jQuery](https://daveceddia.com/angular/handle-dom-events-the-angular-way-without-jquery/)